# How to keep UIIMage aspect ratio and side padding width and prevent the height from exceeding the parent view height

Tags: autolayout

I have a UIIMageView in the middle of UIView.

I would like to keep a ratio of

1) 0.36:0.64 for the UIIMageView

2) to fill the width of the UIImageView to the UIView with a little padding at the right and left (e.g. UIIMageView is 0.9 of the width of UIView)

It works well on larger device with ratio almost equal to 0.36:0.64 (e.g. iPhone XS Max, iPhone 8 Plus), but not on iPhone 4s.

***Desired output iPhone XS Max:***
[image]

***Problematic output iPhone 8 Plus:***

[image]

**The height of the UIImageView is more than the height of the UIView which is not desirable**

Current constraints:

[image]

I know I can't have a fixed 0.9 width. But what should I replace it with in storyboard? I need the image to fill the screen as much as possible but have the same aspect ratio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want *"a little padding"* ... I'll use `20-pts` for this example, and assume you mean you want ***at least*** 20-pts on each side *and* top and bottom.

You can do this using `>=` values, plus width and height constraints with `Priority` set to less-than `1000`.

Take a look at these constraints:

[image]

We've set the aspect-ratio to `36:64` (that's the same as `0.36:0.64` but makes a little more sense).

We've set top, bottom, leading and trailing all to `>= 20` ... that prevents any side from getting closer than `20-pts` to the edges (the safe-area edges).

We've set `centerX` and `centerY` constraints, to keep the view centered.

The final step is to set the image view's `width` and `height` equal to the width and height of the view's safe-area, ***but*** we give each one a `Priority` of `750`.

In plain language, this says: make the imageView as wide and tall as possible, ***without violating*** the edge-padding, and ***always*** keep the aspect-ratio.

Here's how it looks on a XS:

[image]

on an 8:

[image]

and on a 4S:

[image]

and, here's how it looks on an 8 rotated to Landscape orientation:

[image]

Comment: Great thanks @DonMag, your explanation in layman terms is very helpful. Just one more thing, I still can't fathom the priority value. Why set it to 750 when setting it to 999 works? The "centerY and center X" and "36:64" ratio have priority of 1000, why is the priority of padding >= 20 not less than 1000? and only the width and height priority is being reduce? I've tried changing the padding priority to 999 and width and height priority as 998 and it still works.

Comment: Setting the padding to `>= 20` is a constraint that we *do not* want to give up, so we leave it at 1000. Lowering that priority could allow auto-layout to drop below 20, and we'd lose the padding. For lowering the priorities, you *could* use values like 999 or 998, etc, I used 750 as it is one of the defined levels (`.defaultHigh`).